# Concrete5, Imageflow and Fancybox JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, concrete5

I know the post seems long, but I'm sure there's a very simple solution. Please read through.

Ok so I have me little php here that fetches images:

```
<div id="<?php echo $smallThumbs; ?>" class="imageflow">
<?php 

foreach($images as $imgInfo) {
$f = File::getByID($imgInfo['fID']);

    echo '<img src="';
    echo $f->getRelativePath();
    echo '" longdesc="';
    echo $f->getRelativePath();
    echo '" ';
    echo 'alt="';
    echo $imgInfo['description'];
    echo '"/>';
        ;}; ?>

</div>
```

And this is the fancybox code: http://www.pastie.org/2096958

I pasted it on pastie because it was too long, and I can't make out anything.

I changed the very last bit from

**$(".login-popup-link").fancybox**

to

**$(".imageflow").fancybox**

to get any results at all.  Now the popup shows but it says

*"The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."*

Another place where I'm using the same feature, it runs smoothly with this code for the base image, which when clicked shows the popup

```
<a class="login-popup-link" href="#login-popup"><img src="images/vid.png" width="280" height="216"/></a>
```

Please help!
I've also tried adding 'a' tags in the php code up top, but that just makes the whole gallery disappear.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox works on the <a> tags themselves, but in your code you're pointing it to the <div> that surrounds your 'a' tags. What you need to do is change the javascript from this:

```
$(".imageflow").fancybox({
```

to this:

```
$(".imageflow a").fancybox({
```

Note that if you want multiple images to be grouped together so that you can click arrows in the fancybox to go back and forth between them, you need to give each 'a' tag the same "rel" attribute, for example:

```
echo '<img src="';
echo $f->getRelativePath();
echo '" longdesc="';
echo $f->getRelativePath();
echo '" rel="gallery1"';
echo 'alt="';
echo $imgInfo['description'];
echo '"/>';
```

Comment: okay so i tried this, but it doesn't work. And i think it's because my imageflow.js has an onClick event function built into it. heres the code from my imageflow.js:

http://www.pastie.org/2105774

I've changed the onClick function to: 
**onClick: function() { location.href='index.php#login-popup' }**

So when i use just **$(".imageflow").**, i get a pop-up on click, but it says that the content could not be loaded. And when i place the 'a' tag in the code, the gallery doesnt load at all, which i think is because then imageflow can't parse it

Comment: So from what i could understand, the view.js that i have for the pop-up, it takes the image src from within the 'a' tags which are defined as **a class="login-popup-link" href="#login-popup"**. If i add the 'a' tags to the my php code, imageflow.js can't parse it. if i don't add them, view.js can't parse it. so i need to change one of these in order to get my results. Preferably, i'd want the onClick function removed from imageflow.js, and that parsing capabilities be added to it with the 'a' tags. You think i'm right? if so, is it possible? Thank youuu again :D

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand the issue. You should be able to set up each effect to work with any kind of tag. You might want to read up on jQuery selectors to learn how they work so you'll have a better understanding of the options available to you and what the code for each of these plugins is doing.